# GridViewPager setCurrentItem(int row, int col)

Tags: android, wear-os

Writing an Android Wear app.  Would like to add voice intent to jump to page.  I wrote the code to get to the right row, but its not taking me to the right column.  Is there something wrong that I am doing wrong or is the column jump not supported for the GridViewPager?

Comment: Maybe you will post your code? For me the `setCurrentItem(row, col)` method works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how to share enough code to show off what I'm doing without sharing more than I want to.  I'm doing something like pager.setCurrentItem(3,3); and trying it multiple places.

Comment: I tried to take the GridViewPager example and added this, and I get a NullPointerException     @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        pager.setCurrentItem(0, 0);
    }

Comment: Just cut out ALL unnecessary code and leave ONLY what is relevant (the minimal number of lines that allow to reproduce the issue). Then someone will be able to help you. But apart from that, such cleaning in code (leaving only things that are really essencial to the problem) can avoid many potential bugs or issues and can lead you to resolving your problem by yourself:)

Comment: There's not much left after cutting out how the pages are populated, so instead I tried using the GridViewPager sample code from the SDK, and when I add setCurrentItem I get a NPE.  That's not the same problem I was originally getting, but there must be something about GridViewPager that I do not understand.